# LocationManager: Find out if a certain listener is enabled

Tags: android, locationmanager

Is there a way to know if a listener is enabled?

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListenerGPS);
```

Now the listener receives GPS updates and GPS is on.

While debugging I can see mlocManager.mListeners, which is a HashMap and the first entry is my listener.

Removing the listener will clear the list.:

```
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListenerGPS);
```

I need a way to find out if the listener is active or already removed.

I would need something like

```
boolean enabled = mlocManager.mListeners.size() > 0; // assuming I only use one listener
```

Any ideas (other than using a flag on switch)?

Comment: See my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Listener to work as a service. now use the below method to check is your service is running .

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to build an on/off switch that acts on the current state. While your solution would be feasable I think I rather use a flag which I set accordingly. Still strange that I can not see the listeners.

Comment: how you are seeing the listeners?.the above approach is good for your solution.

Comment: I do not need a service as I do not have background activity. I use a subclass implementing LocationListener, e.g. here: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/get-location-from-gps/

Comment: The link you posted is a basic example of how the `LocationListener` work. In the real world, this example will not be ideal as you will find out. ;)

Comment: if you declare a listener as a class variable then its life time is the life-time of the activity and remain active.now explain wt you want extra to do...

Answer (score -1):

Let me suggest another approach.

Instead of checking if the LocationListener is running or not, you can:

1. Create a `LocationListener` class called `LocalLocationListener` or whatever name you wish.
2. Activate the `LocationListener` in a Service's `onStartCommand` method with:

   this.mLocalLocationListener = new LocalLocationListener(this);
3. On Service's `onDestroy()` method, stop the  `LocationListener` class with:

   mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this.mLocalLocationListener);
4. Lastly, provide a preference option to allow your users to select the frequency with which to update the info returned from the `LocationListener` class. This is an important feature to allow your users to conserve battery's power since doing this:

   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListenerGPS);

   will consume a lot of power as it constantly requesting info from
   the GPS provider. Read
   [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)
   for more info.